# Selenium WebDriver with Java: testing a file upload site

Tags: java, file-upload, selenium-webdriver

How can I test a site like http://www.megafileupload.com/ for testing file upload using Selenium WebDriver? . It does not contain an input box like most of the site in which I can use sendKeys() to send the path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

To Test a site like http://www.megafileupload.com, you can test by Upload a file using Robot class.

Step 1 : By Clicking Select file option in http://www.megafileupload.com opens a pop-up.

Step 2 : From the Pop-up - you have find an option "Drag & drop file or Click here to Browse".

Step 3 : Click over the option opened a file select modal window.

Step 4 : Upload a file by using Robot class.

Step4 Example :

```
StringSelection ss=new StringSelection("C:\\path to file\\example.jpg"); 
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
            Robot rb=new Robot();
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```